# Basic 301 rediret not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a handful of old blog posts to new ones.  Here is my htaccess that I have written and placed in the root directory.  Keep in mind the site is now on linux server and not windows.

```
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=1888 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2025 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=405
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2682 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=549
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2152 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=309
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=1398 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=817
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=1908 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=155
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2162 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=317
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=1889 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=145
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=1951 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=808
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2032 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=238
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2101 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=269
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2147 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=304
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2563 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=449
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2043 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=243
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2224 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=361
redirect 301 /public/recipesdetl.aspx?id=2151 http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=308
```

Comment: Highlight the block and ctl-k to format it as a code block, disabling links :)

Comment: So if it isn't working, what is or isn't it doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can include query strings in the first URI-path in a `Redirect` statement, you'll need to use mod_rewrite's `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1888$
RewriteRule ^/?public/recipesdetl.aspx$ http://www.mysite.com/recipes/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2025$
RewriteRule ^/?public/recipesdetl.aspx$ http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=405 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2682$
RewriteRule ^/?public/recipesdetl.aspx$ http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=549 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2152$
RewriteRule ^/?public/recipesdetl.aspx$ http://www.mysite.com/recipes/?p=309 [L,R=301]
```

etc.